# WCF Service not working due to white-space in soap envelope (Soap Request XML)

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, whitespace

I am facing an issue while calling SOAP API and getting different responses due to single space between envelope and body i.e:

`<s:Envelope><DataRequest>` if I request it like this I receive empty SOAP body from server, but if I send it like this:

`<s:Envelope> <DataRequest>` I receive proper response from server side.

Can anyone suggest what to do in this situation? Should I ask server side dev team to do some changes? If so, what changes should be done?

Comment: Can you post the entire requests ?

Comment: I am trying to add whitespace using BeforeSendRequest, but cannot see this space when sending.

Comment: Even tried to add comments and white space in at message sending via IClientMessageInspector. but final message doesn't have it

Comment: It could be a matter of namespace. That's why you should post the entire request.

Comment: namespace? Please elaborate

Comment: The default namespace of the DataRequest field may be different, epecially if you remove some content, for instance the root field.